# Lower bound on sample size to determine coin fairness

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-deviation, standard-error

This is a conclusion I came to through **very** basic knowledge of statistics and error analysis.

Suppose we want to determine the fairness of a coin. To do this, we need to determine the probability of the coin landing on either Heads or Tails and we do this through repeated flipping. We have an amount of uncertainty we are willing to allow in our measurement of the probability. We define the variable $f$ as follows:
$$f = 
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if the coin lands on Heads} \\
0, & \text{if the coin lands on Tails}
\end{cases}$$
Then our measurement of the probability $P(H)$ of the coin landing on heads is equal to the sample average of $f$, $\bar f$. The formula for the standard error of the measurement of $f$ through $n$ samples is:
$$\Delta f = \frac{\sigma_f}{\sqrt{n}}$$
Now, since $f$ can only have values $0$ and $1$, its standard deviation cannot be greater than $\frac{1}{2}$. So we have:
$$\Delta f < \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$$
So if we flip the coin $n$ times, we can be pretty confident our error in estimating the probability is at most $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$. Rearranging:
$$n<\frac{1}{4(\Delta f)^2}$$
So to measure the probability with an error of $\Delta f$ we can be pretty confident we'll need to flip the coin $\frac{1}{4(\Delta f)^2}$ times at most.
Then for example, if I want to determine the probability of the coin landing of Heads within an error of 5%, I'll need to flip it at most 100 times.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Phineas I just edited the title by replacing "upper bound" with "lower bound" because we can control the accuracy of a point estimator only by setting an appropriate lower bound on the sample size (note that by setting an upper bound you cannot as in this case you always have  a sample with size $n=1$). You may find more details in my answer.

Comment: could you let me know your feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Let me first formally express the way commonly used to describe the accuracy of the point estimator $\bar{F_n}$ for the parameter $f$.

Let the following inequality hold:

$$\mathbb P \left (|\text{error}_n|:=|\bar{F_n}-f| < \epsilon \right) \ge \delta.$$

Then, we say that the probability of that the error of estimating $f$ using $\bar{F}$ is less than $\epsilon>0$ is at least $\delta$ (confidence level).

Now let us find out how $n$, $\epsilon>0$, and $\delta$ are related. One way is to use Chebyshev inequality. Using this inequality, and noting that $f(1-f) \le \frac{1}{4}$ for $f \in [0,1]$, we obtain

$$\mathbb P \left (|\text{error}_n| <  \epsilon \right) \ge 1-\frac{1}{4n\epsilon^2}.$$

From this, we can make the following key observations:

1. When $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta$ are given, if $n\ge \frac{1}{4(1-\delta)\epsilon^2}$ then $\mathbb P \left (|\text{error}_n| < \epsilon \right) \ge \delta $.
2. When $n$ and $\epsilon>0$ are given, then $\delta$ is **at least** $1-\frac{1}{4n\epsilon^2}$, i.e, $\mathbb P \left (|\text{error}_n| < \epsilon \right) \ge \delta $ holds for **some** $\delta \ge 1-\frac{1}{4n\epsilon^2}.$
3. When $n$ and $\delta>0$ are given, then  $\epsilon$ is **at most** $ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{(1-\delta)n}}$, i.e, $\mathbb P \left (|\text{error}_n| < \epsilon \right) \ge \delta $ holds for **some** $\epsilon \le \frac{1}{2\sqrt{(1-\delta)n}}$.

Using the above observations, your statements can be corrected/improved.

---

Your first statement in the OP

> If we flip the coin $n$ times, we can be pretty confident our error in estimating the probability is at most $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$.

can be corrected/improved as follows (using the **third** observation):

> If we flip the coin $n$ times we can be pretty confident (with probability $\delta$ ) that our error in estimating the probability $f$ is at most $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{(1-\delta)n}}$.

---

Your next statement in the OP

> To measure the probability with an error of $\Delta f$ we can be pretty confident we'll need to flip the coin $\frac{1}{4(\Delta f)^2}$ times at most.

can be corrected/improved as follows (using the **first** observation):

> To **estimate** the probability $f$ with an error of $\Delta f$ we can be pretty confident (with probability $\delta$ ) if we flip the coin $\frac{1}{4(1-\delta){(\Delta f})^2}$ times **at least**.

---

The last statement in the OP

> If I want to determine the probability of the coin landing of heads within an error of 5%, I'll need to flip it **at most** 100 times.

can be corrected/improved as follows (using the **first** observation):

> If I want to determine the probability of the coin landing of heads within an error of 5% and confidence $\delta$, I'll need to flip it **at least** $\frac{100}{(1-\delta)}$ times.

---

Note that the value of confidence $\delta$ considerably changes the minimum sample size. For example, If "pretty confident" by you is translated to the confidence level of $\delta=0.99$, then to have a maximum error of $\Delta f=0.05$, we need to flip the coin **at least 10000 times not 100 times**, which are obtained from the correct $\frac{1}{4(1-\delta){(\Delta f})^2}$ and incorrect $\frac{1}{4{(\Delta f})^2}$ formulas, respectively.